# How to pass dates to pandas date_range

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date, parameter-passing

I would like to supply the start and end date as arguments/parameters into the pandas date_range function but it is not processing them as dates.

Running the following works fine and returns the month:

```
import pandas as pd

date_range = pd.date_range('2019-06-01','2019-06-01',freq='MS').strftime("%Y-%m").tolist()
```

But when I try to run the code passing on beg_date as an argument it does not return anything.

```
beg_date = '2019-06-01'

date_range2 = pd.date_range(beg_date,beg_date,freq='MS').strftime("%Y-%m").tolist()
```

Thanks.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve, since there are some contradicting factors. You pass a date range with start and end on the same day, with a frequence of `Month Start`. And then you want to extract the year + month from that?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to create a script where the user specifies a date as an argument at command line. That date feeds into another piece of code. But I also want to pass on that date to another bit of code. It needs the month to loop through a series of files that have a match of the month in their title and then to perform an action - such as                                                                                                        
   For month in date_range2:

Comment: All. I've found a solution using a combination of date functions. Will upload solution once cleaned up. Thanks!